# Building C# and SQL Server database dependant application

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, deployment

Let's say I need to create an application like a books library management system for example that has a front-end like Windows form/WPF and it stores information to database. How to approach making such a solution.

Do we need to create a database first with all tables in C# or is the other way.. SQL to C#?

How do people generally do this? Can someone point me to a sample free project or a book that does this to reinforce my understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both ways are possible. People usually only focus on one side and use a tool for the other.

- Database first approach: Codesmith is an exemple of tool that'll generate C# files after you created the database.
- Code first approach: Entity Framework is (an exemple) for the other way around, you write your model in C# and it will generate the database accordingly.

Now pointing you at one or the other would be a bit subjective and also not really match Stack Overflow spirit.